# Why isn’t there a output when i try to print the list of lines from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing an exercise with the help of tutorial of python, trying to combine the codes used to read contents of file line by line and to make a list of lines from a file. The output I expected is that the text will be printed 2 times, which doesn’t work.

My operating system is Windows 10.
I use sublime text 3.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line.strip())
```

Output:

```
In Python you can use list.
In Python you can use class.
In Python you can use dictionary.
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Why doesn’t `print(line.strip())` work?

Comment: What contents does your file have?

Comment: In Python you can use list.
In Python you can use class.
In Python you can use dictionary. One sentence one line.

Comment: hint: is `lines` empty?

Comment: `f` is an iterator and it empties in the first for loop, So `lines = f.readlines()` gives you an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `f` is a file iterator which is completely exhausted after the loop (it is one-time consumable). There is nothing in `f` to read from and hence `f.readlines()` returns an empty list.

In fact, if you want to iterate over file lines over again, you should use `f.readlines()` to store list and iterate over that list any number of times.

Comment: Namely, the content of file can only be printed one time?

Comment: @yuitaaaa, yes (with your code). For multiple iterations, see my second paragraph.